# Adjuntar subconsulta con varias filas a una consulta principal

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito adjuntar la query que un usuario lanza a un informe de estadísticas sobre consultas de larga duración en Amazon Redshift (basado en PostgreSQL). Estas las obtengo de la siguiente manera:

```
select query as idquery,wlm_start_time as inicio,queue_time as 
tiempo_en_cola_microseg,exec_time as tiempo_ejecucion_microseg, 
(tiempo_en_cola_microseg+tiempo_ejecucion_microseg) as tiempo_total_microseg 
,state as estado,
mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/3600000000) as integer),24) || ':' || 
mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/60000000) as integer),60) || ':' || 
mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/1000000) as integer),60)  as 
duracion_hhmmss,
case tiempo_total_microseg
when tiempo_total_microseg>28800000000
then 'CRITICAL' else 'WARNING'
end as situacion
from stv_wlm_query_state
where tiempo_total_microseg >= 14400000000
order by duracion_hhmmss;
```

Ahora, necesito coger el campo `query` y buscar todo el texto (el `select` en si) en otra tabla:

```
select * from stl_querytext where query = 1319600;
```

El problema es que esta última consulta arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, la sentencia la divide en varias secuencias. Yo necesito que toda la consulta aparezca en un único campo, para adjuntarlo a la consulta de arriba, ya que ese resultado se exporta en `.CSV`

¿De qué manera podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Después de releerlo varias veces, creo entender que lo que necesitas es *unir* todos los trozos del campo `text` para hacer una única *query*.

Algo tal que así:

```
select listagg(text) 
  within group (order by sequence) as fullquery,
from stl_querytext where query = 1319600;
```

Información de `listagg`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

Comment: Correcto, solo que necesitaría pasarla por cada query que obtengo en la primera consulta de la pregunta, para que como último campo salga dicho `text`.

Es decir, al final, debería quedar:

`idquery inicio tiempo_en_cola_microseg tiempo_ejecucion_microseg tiempo_total_microseg estado duracion_hhmmss situacion text`

Comment: No he querido complicar más la respuesta. Lo recomendable sería hacer un *join* de las dos tablas.

Comment: eso fue lo primero que intenté, pero siempre me daba error. Este fue el último código que probé:

`...  as duracion_hhmmss,
listagg(text) 
within group (order by sequence) as fullquery,
case tiempo_total_microseg
when tiempo_total_microseg>28800000000
then 'CRITICAL' else 'WARNING'
end as situacion
from stv_wlm_query_state a, stl_querytext b
where a.query=b.query and tiempo_total_microseg >= 14400000000 
order by duracion_hhmmss;`

Error: column "a.query" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Sí, es comprensible. Será mejor crear una vista para que no se vea tan complicada la query: `create temp view fullqueries as select query, listagg(text) within group (order by sequence) as fullquery from stl_querytext`.